# Fix this test: Functional-Reactive Programming Tutorial

Tags: javascript, oop, jasmine, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm studying through the tutorial at http://reactivex.io/learnrx/. I'm on **Exercise 19 - Reducing with an Initial Value:** *Sometimes when we reduce an array, we want the reduced value to be a different type than the items stored in the array. Let's say we have an array of videos and we want to reduce them to a single map where the key is the video id and the value is the video's title.*

As far as the tutorial is concerned, I've solved it:

```
function exercise19() {
    var videos = [
        {
            "id": 65432445,
            "title": "The Chamber"
        },
        {
            "id": 675465,
            "title": "Fracture"
        },
        {
            "id": 70111470,
            "title": "Die Hard"
        },
        {
            "id": 654356453,
            "title": "Bad Boys"
        }
    ];

  return videos.reduce(function(accumulatedMap, video) {
      var copyOfAccumulatedMap = Object.create(accumulatedMap);
      copyOfAccumulatedMap[video.id] = video.title; // <-- My solution

      return copyOfAccumulatedMap;
  }, {});
} // end of overall function
```

To verify your solution you click, "Run." If it runs correctly then you get to move on to the next exercise. I did and it gave me the next exercise. My test suite tells me differently.

While trying to solve it, I created this test:

```
 it("should be able to reduce to an object with id's for keys", function() {

    var output = [{
      "65432445": "The Chamber",
      "675465": "Fracture",
      "70111470": "Die Hard",
      "654356453": "Bad Boys"
    }];

    expect(exercise19()).toEqual(output);

  }); // end it
```

(I got the output from the tutorial.)

The problem I'm having is the test continues to fail:

> Expected [ Object({ 654356453: 'Bad Boys' }) ] to equal [ Object({
>   65432445: 'The Chamber', 675465: 'Fracture', 70111470: 'Die Hard',
>   654356453: 'Bad Boys' }) ].

So it seems like it's only picking up the final property, the 'bad boys' property, in the test. I'm thinking that, with the way reduce works and Object.create, that the other properties are there, but they're on the prototype. How can I get this test to pass..?

## UPDATE:

I fixed this in a pull-request. These tutorial no uses Object.assign, instead of Object.create. It is now testable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a known issue with Jasmine `toEqual` -- it just ignores properties from prototypes. You probably could use something like that in the test:

```
// ...
expect(exercise19()).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
  "654356453": "Bad Boys"
  // rest data here
}));
```

Comment: Awww... I really wanted this to work. :D It's still coming back fail, but this was very helpful. The correct answer in the tutorial comes back as an object inside an array, so jasmine.objectContaining doesn't like the result. I'm wondering if I have to make my own matcher. Do all jasmine matchers utilize hasOwnProperty internally?

Comment: This works, but only if I keep the object down to "Bad Boys":     expect(exercise19()).toEqual(jasmine.arrayContaining([{
      654356453: "Bad Boys"
    }]));

Comment: For that matter, so does this: expect(exercise19()).toEqual([{ 654356453: "Bad Boys" }]);

Comment: This is about as good of an answer as can be expected without a hack.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` creates a new object with the prototype of the object specified in the first argument - you are not copying the object at all, you are creating a new object with Object's prototype - i.e. you're doing a long winded `var copyOfAccumulatedMap = {}`

instead, do this

```
return videos.reduce(function(accumulatedMap, video) {
    accumulatedMap[video.id] = video.title;
    return accumulatedMap;
}, {});
```

Comment: Object gets copied, but it's properties are in prototype. Anyway, the exercise gets passed so the problem is in test not in the code.

Comment: have you run the original code? it does not produce the expected output - the website should never have passed the code

Comment: if you do `exercise19()[65432445]` it gives you `"The Chamber"` so the result is totally correct, all the objects are in place.